# How to swap across center in array?

Tags: c++

Write a C++ function swapAcrossCenter(),that takes pointer array and array size as argument
and swap its values across center. The size of array should be an odd number.
Example: suppose values are 2 5 6 7 8
Before function call (Input): 2 5 6 7 8
After function call (Output): 8 7 6 5 2
But want general function and size of array given by user.
It is hard code in which size is fixed.I want to make a code in which the odd size will be given by user.Then program find center and swap the array.

```cpp
int size =5;
int array[size] ={1,2,3,4,5};
if(size==5)
{
    int a,b;
    a =array[0];
    b=array[1];
    array[0]=array[4];
    array[1]=array[3];
    array[3]=b;
    array[4]=a;
}

for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
{
    cout<<array[i];
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Can you show use some coding effort that you've made? You're more likely to get your code fixed if we have something to fix. You are *extremely unlikely* to get code written from scratch for you.

Comment: Iint main()
{

 int size =5;
int array[size] ={1,2,3,4,5};
if(size==5)
 {  int a,b;
     a =array[0];
     b=array[1];
  array[0]=array[4];
  array[1]=array[3];
  array[3]=b;
  array[4]=a;
 }
 
for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
{
 cout<<array[i];
}
return 0; 
}

Comment: it is hard code.but I want general code in which user give odd size.

Comment: Edit your question to include the code - posted as a comment, it's very hard to understand.

Comment: I Edit the code.

Comment: Start with the first sentence: write down the appropriate function prototype. Then think about the relationship between the size and the indexing. ("Half the size" will come in handy.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Evolution: From C to C++ . . .

First you need to notice that your function reverses an array.

Then. You should never use C-Style plain arrays in C++. Use `std::array` or `std::vector` instead. These classes know the size of the underlying array.

The last one is the best solution. It does not matter how many elements the vector has. Reverse works always.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <vector>

// Solution 1: Pure C-Code, full manual implementation
void swapAcrossCenter1(int arr[], int size) {
    int first{ 0 };
    int last{ size };

    while ((first != last) && first != --last) {
        int temp = arr[first];
        arr[first++] = arr[last];
        arr[last] = temp;
    }
}

// Solution 2: Pure C-Code, use swap subfunction
void swapManual(int* v1, int* v2) {
    int temp = *v1;
    *v1 = *v2;
    *v2 = temp;
}
void swapAcrossCenter2(int arr[], int size) {
    int first{ 0 };
    int last{ size };

    while ((first != last) && first != --last) {
        swapManual(&arr[first++], &arr[last]);
    }
}

// Solution 3: A little bit of C++ Code, use std::algorithm for swap
void swapAcrossCenter3(int arr[], int size) {
    int first{ 0 };
    int last{ size };

    while ((first != last) && first != --last) {
        std::iter_swap(&arr[first++], &arr[last]);
    }
}

// Solution 4: A little bit more of C++ Code, use std::algorithm for reverse
void swapAcrossCenter4(int arr[], int size) {
    std::reverse(&arr[0], &arr[size]);
}



int main() {

    int test[5] = { 2,4,6,8,10 };

    // Solution 1: Pure C-Code, full manual implementation
    swapAcrossCenter1(test, 5);
    std::copy(&test[0], &test[5], std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, "\n")); std::cout << "\n";

    // Solution 2: Pure C-Code, use swap subfunction
    swapAcrossCenter2(test, 5);
    std::copy(&test[0], &test[5], std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, "\n")); std::cout << "\n";

    // Solution 3: A little bit of C++ Code, use std::algorithm for swap
    swapAcrossCenter3(test, 5);
    std::copy(&test[0], &test[5], std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, "\n")); std::cout << "\n";

    // Solution 4: A little bit more of C++ Code, use std::algorithm for reverse
    swapAcrossCenter4(test, 5);
    std::copy(&test[0], &test[5], std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, "\n")); std::cout << "\n";

    // Solution 5: C++ Code, use std::algorithm for reverse, but with plain C-Style array
    std::reverse(&test[0], &test[5]);
    std::copy(&test[0], &test[5], std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, "\n")); std::cout << "\n";

    // Solution 6: C++ Code, use std::algorithm for reverse, with std::vector
    std::vector<int> v{ 1,3,5,7,9 };
    std::reverse(v.begin(), v.end());
    std::copy(v.begin(), v.end(), std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, "\n")); std::cout << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```